# Javascript load markdown file raw data into array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a React project and I want to load some raw (string) Markdown files to an array of objects.

## What I want to do - but it doesn't work:

**links_file.js**

```
export const links = ["path to file 1.md", "path to file 2.md", ...]
```

**logic.js**

```
import { links } from "links_file.js"

componentDidMount() {
      links.map( (link, index) => {
         fetch(link).then(resp => {
              return response.text()
         }).then( text => {
              // Make a shallow copy of the files
              let files = [...this.state.files];
              // Make a shallow copy of the file to mutate
              let updatedFile = {...files[index], content: text};
              // Make a shallow copy of the item to mutate and replace the property
              files[index] = updatedFile;
              //Set the state to the new copy
              this.setState({files});
         })
      })
}
```

> Console logging **text** gives me the index.html instead of the raw md content I want.

## This works:

```
import file1 from 'path to file 1.md';
import file2 from 'path to file 2.md';

componentDidMount() {
     fetch(file1).then(resp => {
          return response.text()
     }).then( text => {
          this.setState(file1: text);
     })
}
```

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* Could you be more specific? What are the symptoms? How do you know that it doesn't work? Is `this.state.files` only filled with 1 of the 2 (or more) results?

Comment: @3limin4t0r I've updated the question explaining why it doesn't work. As for tye `this.state.files`, that an array of objects, the object has a property `content` which I want to set with the raw data from those files.

Comment: Does it fetch the right files? For instance, if you look into the network tab of the developer tools, does it request the files you expect?

Comment: @A_A The files are being fetched correctly. But the Fetch status is 304: Not modified.
Well, flushing the cache returns a 200 when the files are fetched

Comment: And if you `console.log(link, text)`, it gives you `"path to file 1.md", "<!doctype><!-- index.html -->"`?

Comment: @A_A Exactly, console logging that, prints the path of the file and index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using `create-react-app`, make sure your files are in the `public` folder

they need to be exposed via a web URL first, for you to use the `fetch` API

you can't `fetch` files from your file system

working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-read-text-files-from-public-sk4es

[image: 1]

Comment: Thank you @oieduardorabelo! Moving those files to the public folder solved the issue! :)